# Python Flask-restful multiple api endpoints

Tags: python, flask, endpoint, flask-restful

How to check what route has been used?

Using @api with Flask-restful and Python at the moment I'm not doing it in a  clean way by checking `api.endpoint` value.

How do I do it correctly?

```
@api.route('/form', endpoint='form')
@api.route('/data', endpoint='data')
class Foobar(Resource):
    def post(self):
        if api.endpoint == 'api.form':
            print('form')
        elif api.endpoint == 'api.data':
            print('data')
```

EDIT:

Should I split it into two classes?

Comment: what guide are you following on Flask? I've never seen this unusual style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am in no way a professional with flask so please do take my answer with a grain of salt. First of all I would definitely split it into 2 different classes just to have a better overview of what you are doing. Also as a rule of thumb I would always split the apis and write its own logic for a higher degree of granularity.

Second if you want to have a look at https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.owns_endpoint. This might be of assistance for you.

Answer (score 3):

I am new with python and flask.

I think something like the following should work for you:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Data(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print("data")
        return{"type": "data"}


class Form(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print("form")
        return{"type": "form"}


api.add_resource(Form, '/form')
api.add_resource(Data, '/data')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Also you have use seperate files for the classes for a cleaner code like:

form.py

```
from flask_restful import Resource


class Form(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print("form")
        return{"type": "form"}
```

data.py

```
from flask_restful import Resource


class Data(Resource):
    def post(self):
        print("data")
        return{"type": "data"}
```

services.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api
from data import Data
from form import Form

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


api.add_resource(Form, '/form')
api.add_resource(Data, '/data')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080)
```

Hope this helps.